# Certain raster layers cannot be merged in GDAL

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I attempted to merge a number of raster maps with GDAL in QGIS but got the following error:

```
GDAL execution console output
             
             0...10...20...30...40...50...60..ERROR 5: C:/Users/reube/OneDrive/maps/stiched_1/A16_cropped.tif: GDALDataset::GetRasterBand(4) - Illegal band #
             
             
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.10\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal_merge.py", line 11, in 
             
              sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.10\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py", line 530, in main
             
              fi.copy_into(t_fh, band, band, nodata, verbose)
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.10\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py", line 284, in copy_into
             
              return raster_copy(s_fh, sw_xoff, sw_yoff, sw_xsize, sw_ysize, s_band,
             
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.10\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py", line 65, in raster_copy
             
              if s_band.GetMaskFlags() != gdal.GMF_ALL_VALID:
             
             AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetMaskFlags'
```

Comment: you indicate only 1 geotif file, what are you trying to merge?

Comment: I would check first if this applies to your source data `All the images must be in the same coordinate system and have a matching number of bands,` https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html.

Comment: As per [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts